# How to get the id of html list item using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, html-lists

I wanna get the id of `<li>`  using jquery. I was able to get the text using `alert($(this).text())` but when I tried `alert($(this).id())` it says `undefined`.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
 ul {
  list-style-type: none;
 }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery1.6.4min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" > 
  $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#list li').click(function() {
    alert($(this).id());
    alert($(this).text());
   });
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <ul id="list">
  <li id="l1">Value 1</li>
  <li id="l2">Value 2</li>
  <li id="l3">Value 3</li>
  <li id="l4">Value 4</li>
  <li id="l5">Value 5</li>
  <li id="l6">Value 6</li>
  <li id="l7">Value 7</li>
  <li id="l8">Value 8</li>
  <li id="l9">Value 9</li>
  <li id="l10">Value 10</li>
  <li id="l11">Value 11</li>
  <li id="l12">Value 12</li>
 </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Plase help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should get attributes from elements using the [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) function:

```
alert($(this).attr('id'));
```

The jQuery object doesn't have a method called `id()` which is why you're getting the result as `undefined`.

Answer (score 3):

it's actually `$(this).attr('id')`, not `$(this).id()`.

Answer (score 3):

id is an attribute. You need

```
alert($(this).attr('id'))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#list li').click(function() {
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
    alert($(this).text());
   });
  });
```

Check jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/72xsm/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery 1.6 + then you should use this code.

```
var id = $(this).prop('id');
```